# Issues while trying to run git uninstall.sh on Mac OS

Tags: macos, git, shell

I wanted to try to update Git on my Mac OS to the latest version and it says to run the provided `uninstall.sh` first. I must confess that I ran the pkg before reading the "Read me". Not sure if that screwed it all up ...

Now I am not big with the terminal and found the following command to run a shell script:

```
$ sh uninstall
```

but that resulted in:

```
/usr/sbin/uninstall: /usr/sbin/uninstall: cannot execute binary file
```

where I got stuck now.

Any idea what I have to do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the `uninstall.sh` packaged with your previous distribution of Git, as explained in "[Install and Update to latest version Git on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-update-latest-version-git-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/)":

### Upgrading Git from a previous version to the latest 2.0.1

> If you have previously installed Git you can upgrade to the latest version by uninstalling the previous install using the uninstall.sh file with the installation.
>
> Go through the same process of downloading and mounting and the `.dmg`  – then launch the Terminal.

[image: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/upgrading-git-osx.png]

Comment: Very helpful article! One section that confused me a bit under "Trumping Xcodes Older Git", though, was:

"To run the lastest version you need to adjust your shell path:
/usr/local/git/bin/git
...add the above path to the beginning of your shell path ..."

followed by
"So add in
/usr/local/git/bin
to the path similar to the below:"

I first added /usr/local/git/bin/git to $PATH which didn't work, found out how to unset this variable again and tried /usr/local/git/bin next, which worked!

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and uninstall.sh are two different things. The former is a binary that comes with the os, the latter is a shell script that comes with the package.

Try: sh uninstall.sh instead